# Using Redemption (RDO) Can No Longer Change Other User's Mailbox Contact Items

Tags: c#, outlook-redemption

I have a program running under an admin account, who is a power user who has write permissions into other Exchange mailboxes. Using the old Exchange 2003 server (name altered for illustration purposes), I was able to:

```
session.LogonExchangeMailbox(usrEmail,"old.Exchange2003.com");
```

and make changes to the user's contacts.

After migration to the new Exchange 2010 server (name altered), no changes are reflected into user's mailbox.

```
session.LogonExchangeMailbox(usrEmail, "new.Exchange2010.com")
```

NOR

```
session.LogonExchangeMailbox(UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress, "new.Exchange2010.com");
session.GetSharedMailbox(usrEmail);

//followed by attempts to change the user's contacts.
```

What is missing? I would appreciate any ideas helping to solve this issue. Thanks!

Comment: So which method errors our or behaves unexpectedly? Are you saying modifying RDOContactItem object and then calling RDOContactItem.Save does not save the changes?

Comment: If I try to log on using the old Exchange 2003 server I get:    System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was caught
  HResult=-2147221219
  Message=Error in IMAPISession::OpenMsgStore: MAPI_E_FAILONEPROVIDER   Using the new Exchange 2010 server there is no error, but after I save those contacts, they don't show up into the user's mailbox.

Comment: Please show your code that open, modifies, and saves the contacts.

Comment: @Dmitry Streblechenko      RDOFolder contacts = session.GetDefaultFolder(rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
                        RDOFolders folders = contacts.Folders;
                        RDOFolder subfolder = folders["CRM Contacts"];
                        RDOItems items = subfolder.Items;
                        RDOMail msg = items.Add("IPM.Contact.NewCRMContactForm");
                        RDOContactItem rci = (RDOContactItem)msg;

Comment: RDOItems items = subfolder.Items; rci.Save();
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(rci);
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(msg);
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(items);
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(subfolder);
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folders);
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(contacts);
                        RDOMail msg = items.Add("IPM.Contact.NewCRMContactForm");
                        RDOContactItem rci = (RDOContactItem)msg;

Comment: @Dmitry Streblechenko: The portion of the code which is creating and saving the contacts works fine. The trouble is that the contacts don't appear into the other user's mailbox. They show up fine if I save them into the admin's account.

Comment: Another hint: Accessing mailbox is different on 2010 since you have go through the CAS server. What does this mean?

Comment: Well, you always open the default Contacts folder (RDOSession.GetDefaultFolder) and its subfolder. Why do you expect the contacts to appear in some other mailbox?

Comment: @Dmitry Streblechenko: because that's the whole point of using Redemption with my program, which runs under a power user. The program logs on to the Exchange mailbox of another user and creates contacts there, based on some values from a database.

Comment: @Dmitry Streblechenko: in other words, the admin user has the email  UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress, and I am trying to log on to the Exchange server  to another user's mailbox, using another valid, specified user email address in the same domain.

Comment: So you are calling LogonHostedExchangeMailbox specifying different SMTP addresses for the first and second parameters?

Comment: @Dmitry Streblechenko: YES! Your suggested solution to use LogonHostedExchangeMailbox works. Many thanks! Please provide your last comment as an answer. I'll be more than glad to accept it!

Comment: @Dmitry Streblechenko: actually using LogonHostedExchangeMailbox worked partially. When I run it logged at myself, it wrote into my mailbox. When I tried to run it logged in as admin, and write into my mailbox, it didn't work.

Comment: Using Redemption & Exchange Server 2010, what are the prerequisites for a software running under the Active Directory account A to be able to write to the mailbox contacts of another account B? Both accounts A and B are on the same domain.

Comment: If you are using LogonHostedExchangeMailbox, you can go across domains as long as the credentials are good.

Comment: @Dmitry Streblechenko: is LogonHostedExchangeMailbox supposed to work when I provide the SMPTEmail of user B, but the credentials of power user A? Are there any settings on the Exchange 2010 server side to enable user A to write into the mailbox of user B?

Comment: Yes, if the user A has send as/receive as right for mailbox B, you should be able to log in using the credentials of user A. Or you can log to the mailbox of user A, then use RDOSession.GetSharedMailbox(UserB)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the solution involves using the EWS Managed API.